Как получить список id тем (threads) в форуме телеграмм при помощи бота. C#
Допустим если отправить приветсвенное сообщение в чат то бот может получить  chatid и id темы в которую отправил сообщение, но вот как получить списо id всех тем я не понимаю. Буду благодарен

скорее всего в API нет такого функционала, но можно получить идентификатор нужной темы вручную, как показано тут
